# ZFS log partition got deleted: how to recover the partition table of this ZFS partition to recover the ZFS partition table?

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, partition

I hadn't turned on my NAS system for some time, and something regarding ZFS broke when I turned the system back on.

The setup for my ZFS pool is three 8TB drives in RAIDZ, with an NVME drive containing a ZIL slog partition and a cache partition. When I checked the drives in gparted, the ZIL log partition was somehow deleted and listed as unallocated.

From what I researched, it looked like the partition table for the pool was stored on that partition, so the pool no longer appears in the zfs/zpool programs.

My best guess is to try to recover the partition table for the ZIL log partition, which should restore the ZFS pool partition table with it, but I don't know of a safe to do this without risking losing the ZFS partition table. Would should I try to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

So I did get a solution from a friend.
Things that I did try that did not work:

```
zpool list
zpool status
zpool import
```

These all printed the message `no pools available` or `no pools available to import`
My friend however suggested that I run: `zpool import -D POOLNAME` using my poll's name, and it worked.